# Get .NET type declaring an interface

Tags: .net, reflection

Let's assume type MyType implements interface IMyInterface. How to find type declaring an interface ? For example,

```
class UnitTest 
{
  MyTypeBase : IMyInterface  { }
  MyType : MyTypeBase  { }

  void Test() {
    Type declaration = FindDeclaration(typeof(MyType), typeof(IMyInterface));
    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(MyTypeBase), declaration) 
  }
```

Comment: Is your question this: If I only know the interface-type, IMyInterface, how do I find any class type that implements this interface? Is that it? You basically want to search for any and all classes that happens to implement that interface?

Comment: Or is it that you have two classes, like you showed, and you're looking at the bottom-most (descendant-wise) class, and want to know how far up the tree you need to go to find the topmost class that implements an interface?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that your question is not altogether clear. I read the first line as "Let's assume my car is read. How do I find a red car?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `GetInterface` or `GetInterfaces` methods of the `Type`.

For example you could do this:

```
Type declaration = typeof(MyType).GetInterface("IMyInterface");
Assert.IsNotNull(declaration)
```

Or you could call `GetInterfaces` and loop through the results until you find `IMyInterface`.

Sources:

[Type.GetInterface(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx)

[Type.GetInterfaces()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, It turns out that iterating through interfaces calling GetInterfaces is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would walk up `Type.BaseType` until you've got to the level you want?

Comment: Well, thanks, this works for classes. But this does not work well for interfaces.

Comment: What? Didn't you want to find the class, not the interface?

Comment: I mean, MyType and MyTypeBase are classes just for sample. if MyType  is interface and MyTypeBase is interface it makes difference.

Comment: But at runtime you have an object. You call .GetType() on that, and you walk up .BaseType until you find what you want. Have you written the code? Maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: I can't use .BaseType for interface type. As I know, for interfaces I can use .GetInterfaces() but is not very elegant.